# Ideas on getting data from external users?

Tags: google-app-maker

Curious if anyone has thoughts on building apps that include data from external users (not necessarily being able to log-in, but just submit forms).

I can wire up something that has Google Forms moving data into Cloud SQL but it seems janky - would be great to be able to build pages that have anonymous data submit capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible alternative to Google Forms with some [configured triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder) will be public stand alone web app that will gather data from end users and push it to the same DB as App Maker deployment. However, this options seems to be way more labor intensive.